# VueJS routes don't allow for a null parameter

Tags: vue.js

I wanted to make a search query for Firebase and have the property in my Search view get it from the URL passed as my search is inside my navbar.

I want my user to type in the search box, hit enter, and be able to view the queried data from firebase. However, when I set my router to have the Search page include parameters - it mandates there be a parameter every time even if I set the default value for the property to: "".

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show some code for your routes?